# Linker error - undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am creating a program, but when I run it I am getting these errors:

```
/tmp/ccYLF4IM.o: In function `main':
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Human::Human()'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Orc::Orc()'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `Orc::~Orc()'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `Orc::~Orc()'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `Human::~Human()'
maingame.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `Human::~Human()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have looked over my code, I am running all the .cpp files and .h files together. I am not sure what the problem can be. I know there are other questions regarding this, but I can not seem to find the answer I am looking for. I have checked the capitalization of everything and I've even deleted everything and started again just to make sure. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
//main.cpp
#include "Human.h"
#include "Orc.h"

using namespace std;

//Main.cpp
int main()
{
    //Character cc;
    Human H;
    Orc O;
    char choice;
    char userC;
    cout << "Welcome!\n";
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Pick your choice:\n";
    cout << "A -- Human\n";
    cout << "B -- Orc\n";
    cin >> choice;

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
//Character.h
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Character
{
    protected:
                float characterTotal;
    public:                 
                virtual int createCharacter() = 0; //Pure virtual function
                Character();
                ~Character();   
};

#endif
```

---

```
//Character.cpp
#include "Character.h"
Character::Character()
{
//ctor
}

Character::~Character()
{
//dtor
}
```

---

```
//human.h
#ifndef HUMAN_H
#define HUMAN_H

#include "Character.h"

using namespace std;

class Human : public Character 
{
    private:
                int characterStrength;
                int characterDexterity;
                int characterIntelligence;
                string characterType;
                int characterTotal;

    public:
                Human();//Constructor 
                                ~Human();

                int getStrength ()
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterStrength;

                    return characterStrength;
                }

                int getDexterity ()
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterDexterity;

                    return characterDexterity;
                }

                int getIntelligence ()
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number from 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> characterIntelligence;

                    return characterIntelligence;
                }

                string getType ()
                {
                    cout << "Please choose one of the following\n";
                    cout << "A -- Paladin \n";
                    cout << "B -- Ranger \n";
                    cout << "C -- Wizard \n";\
                    cin >> characterType;

                    return characterType;
                }

                virtual int createCharacter()
                {
                    characterTotal = characterStrength + characterIntelligence + characterDexterity;
                    return characterTotal;
                }
};

#endif
```

---

```
//Human.cpp
#include "Human.h"
Human::Human()
{
//ctor
}

Human::~Human()
{
//dtor
}
```

---

```
//orc.h
#ifndef ORC_H
#define ORC_H

#include "Character.h"

using namespace std;

class Orc : public Character
{
    private:
                int characterStrength;
                int characterDexterity;
                int characterIntelligence;
                int chaD;
                int chaI;
                int chaS;
                string characterClan;
                int characterTotal;

    public:
                Orc(); //Constructor
                        ~Orc();

                int getStrength()
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number between 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> chaS;
                    characterStrength = chaS + 2;

                    return characterStrength;
                }

                int getDexterity()
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number between 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> chaD;
                    characterDexterity = chaD - 2;

                    return characterDexterity;
                }

                int getIntelligence()
                {
                    cout << "Enter a number between 0 to 18\n";
                    cin >> chaI;
                    characterIntelligence = chaI - 2;

                    return characterIntelligence;
                }

                string getClan()
                {
                    cout << "Please choose one of the following\n";
                    cout << "A -- Barbarian \n";
                    cout << "B -- Berserker \n";
                    cout << "C -- Vanguard \n";\
                    cin >> characterClan;

                    return characterClan;
                }

                virtual int createCharacter()
                    {
                        characterTotal = characterStrength + characterIntelligence + characterDexterity;
                        return characterTotal;
                    }

};
#endif
```

---

```
//Orc.cpp
#include "Orc.h"
Orc::Orc()
{
//ctor
}

Orc::~Orc()
{
//dtor
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling and linking these files?

Comment: My school uses Secure Shell, so that is how I am compiling them. They are all put into the same folder.

Comment: You open Secure Shell and it automatically compiles and links them for you? Interesting setup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile *all* your source files (not header files) and link them together. At this point, the *most straightforward* way to do that is to just specify all the filenames in one command:

```
g++ maingame.cpp character.cpp human.cpp orc.cpp
```

Large projects generally compile each file individually, then link the resulting `.o` (object) files, but you don't seem to have got to this point yet.

Comment: I just ran it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

immibis has got a point, but i think you should take some time and look into makefiles. Since  it seems you're building quiet a project and it's uncomfortable to compile it every time by hand. [This](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html) tutorial is a good introduction into makefiles. Never stop learning!